# Trouble getting PDF report from webhook endpoint in Laravel using $request->file()

Tags: laravel, copyleaks-api

I'm subscribed to get back the pdf report via a web hook endpoint. The endpoint is being hit but now I having issues in trying to get the file from the request.

I'm using Laravel and I've tried using $request->file() but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The PDF file contained in the body of the (webhook) request. Taking the body, save it to a file as "file.pdf", should make it work.

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever thanks. Any idea how I can access the request body using Laravel's Request